# Direccionamiento de paquetes dentro de la red privada

Tags: redes

¿Como se genera el enrutamiento de un paquete entrante? es decir si yo genero una petición sobre un servidor web desde una pc dentro de una red privada, esta petición saldrá con información de destino al servidor web, pero con datos de origen correspondiente a la IP publica asociada al router conectado a internet.

¿Quien es el que tiene la información de donde debe direccionarse la respuesta, el router o el paquete a la hora de redirigirlo a mi pc?

Comment: El *router*. Échale un vistazo a [Traducción de direcciones de red](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traducci%C3%B3n_de_direcciones_de_red).

Comment: Efectivamente, al equipo que esté haciendo NAT... en realidad podrían ser varios equipos haciendo NAT y el tráfico hay que asegurarse de que se devuelva por el mismo camino de vuelta o no se establecería la conexión.

Comment: Efectivamente es el sistema NAT de traducción de direcciones, aparte de la info que me brindaron encontré el siguiente enlace https://www.xatakamovil.com/conectividad/nat-network-address-translation-que-es-y-como-funciona#:~:text=La%20idea%20es%20sencilla%2C%20hacer,direcci%C3%B3n%20IP%20(IP%20p%C3%BAblica).&text=Tambi%C3%A9n%20se%20utiliza%20para%20conectar%20redes%20dom%C3%A9sticas%20a%20Internet.

El cual explica como a través de la IP y un puerto redirige la petición. Gracias por su respuesta!